# How can I reset my Arduino Micro when I've accidentally disabled the internal USB?

Tags: arduino, atmega, arduino-ide

I think I've hosed up my Arduino Micro.  Now, my Mac doesn't see the serial port at all in the `Tools -> Serial Port` menu in Arduino 1.0.5.

I believe the culprit was this command that I sent to the MCU:

```
PORTD = B10000000;
```

More accurately, here is the program that I tried to send and afterwards, I cannot see the MCU at all anymore.

Any advise on how to restore it to factory settings?

Thanks

```
#define _V0 6   //  V0
#define _V1 7   //  V1

#define _SYNC       0x00
#define _BLACK      0x01
#define _GRAY       0x02
#define _WHITE      0x03

#define _tvNbrLines             262 /* Includes the last 20 lines for the vertical sync! */
#define _tvVSyncNbrLines        20  /* These 20 lines... */

#define _ntscDelayHSyncStart    4.7
#define _ntscDelayBackPorch     6   /* Normally 5.9, but this fixes a timing issue */
#define _ntscDelayFrontPorch    1.4
#define _ntscDelayPerLine       51.5
#define _ntscDelayVSync         58.8

#define _tvPixelWidth           21
#define _tvPixelHeight          16

void generateVSync(void);
void writeBufferLine(int position);
void writeTVLines(void);
void clearFrameBuffer(void);
void fillWhiteFrameBuffer(void);
void fillGrayFrameBuffer(void);
void fillPatternFrameBuffer(void);
void loadSprite(void);

byte frameBuffer[_tvPixelWidth][_tvPixelHeight];    // Video frame buffer

void setup() 
{

    pinMode(_V0, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(_V1, OUTPUT);
    cli();
}


void loop() 
{
    // writeTVLines();
    writeTest2();
}

void writeTest2(void) {

    int i;

    PORTD = B10000000;          // Make the sync high to start with
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        PORTD = B00000000;      // Sync pulse goes low and delay 2.3 microseconds
        delayMicroseconds(1);
        delayMicroseconds(1);
        __asm__("nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t");
        PORTD = B10000000;      // Sync pulse goes high and delay 29.7 microseconds
        delayMicroseconds(29);
        __asm__("nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t");
     }


    //
    // Generate the 5 Field Sync Pulses
    //
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        PORTD = B00000000;      // Sync goes low and delay 27.3 microseconds
        delayMicroseconds(27);
        __asm__("nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t");
        PORTD = B10000000;      // Sync goes high and delay 4.7 microseconds
        delayMicroseconds(1);
        delayMicroseconds(1);
        delayMicroseconds(1);
        delayMicroseconds(1);
        __asm__("nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t");
    }


    //
    // Generate 5 Narrow Equalization pulses
    //
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        PORTD = B00000000;      // Sync pulse goes low and delay 2.3 microseconds
        delayMicroseconds(1);
        delayMicroseconds(1);
        __asm__("nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t");
        PORTD = B10000000;
        delayMicroseconds(29);  // Sync pulse goes high and delay 29.7 microseconds
        __asm__("nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t");
    }

    // Generate 18 Blank Frames
    for(i=0; i < 18; i++) {
        PORTD = B00000000;      // Pull sync pin low -> 0 volts
        delayMicroseconds(4);
        __asm__("nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t");
        PORTD = B10000000;      // Pull sync pin high
        delayMicroseconds(59);
    }

    //   
    // Generate half the Image 
    //
    for(i=0; i < 285; i++) {
        //
        // Front Porch
        // 
        PORTD = B10000000;
        delayMicroseconds(1); // Front Porch: 1.65 microseconds
        __asm__("nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t");

        //
        // Generate sync pulse
        //
        PORTD = B00000000;    // Sync pulse pulled low: 4.7 microseconds
        delayMicroseconds(4);
        __asm__("nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t");

        //
        // Back Porch
        //
        PORTD = B10000000;    // This is the back porch: 5.6 microseconds.
        delayMicroseconds(5);
        __asm__("nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t""nop\n\t");

        //
        // Drawing starts here: Total time available is 53 microseconds
        //
        PORTD = B10000000;    // Draw black
        delayMicroseconds(20);
        PORTD = B11000000;    // Draw white
        delayMicroseconds(10);
        PORTD = B10000000;    // Draw black
        delayMicroseconds(22);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it.

For those that would like to know, what I did was:

1) Plugged the Arduino into a different USB port.

2) Noticed the serial port was now listed.

3) Quickly uploaded a very simple program.

All is well now.   It took me a few tries of resetting the Arduino and pressing `CTRL + U` before I got the timing right.